# Reserved space after an integer (instead of before an integer) in C

Tags: c, format, output

What an output would normally look like if it doesn't have any reserved space (just %d):

```
Number 1 | Gold 5 |
Number 10 | Gold 50 |
Number 100 | Gold 500 |
```

What it would look like if the input has reserved space infront of it (using %3d):

```
Number   1 | Gold   5 |
Number  10 | Gold  50 |
Number 100 | Gold 500 |
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
Number 1   | Gold 5   |
Number 10  | Gold 50  |
Number 100 | Gold 500 |
```

Is there any format I can use with the printf function that would make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%-3d` to left justify the output.